# Get core properties of docx/xlsx from ZIP folder

Tags: javascript, http, sharepoint, zip

I have a docx file, which I've converted into a zip folder by simple means. My task is to edit some core properties of the file and turn it back afterwards.

I have tried out both
http://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/demos/demo2.html,
https://stuk.github.io/jszip/ with more, but sadly without any luck.

The Word file (as a zip-folder) is located on my SharePoint workspace, and I have the full URL to get it.

The aspect of this task is to automate setting the core properties of the docx file without making the website user need to use diverse macros or similar time-consuming tasks.

Examples are much appreciated.